# Decompose a cube into tetrahedra (more than one way)?

Tags: combinatorics, polyhedra, barycentric-coordinates

This must be a standard exercise but I have a shape $[0,1]^3$ and I must express it has the union of tetrahedra joined at the faces.  The vertices and edges are clear:

- $V = \{ 0, 1 \} \times \{ 0, 1 \} \times \{ 0, 1 \}$
- $E = \\ \{ \big((x,y,0)-(x,y,1) \big) : x,y \in \{ 0,1\} \} \cup \\ 
  \{ \big((x,0,y)-(x,1,y) \big) : x,y \in \{ 0,1\} \} \cup \\
  \{ \big((0,x,y)-(1,x,y) \big) : x,y \in \{ 0,1\} \} $

The first two tetrahedra are easy:

- $T_0  = \{ (0,0,0), (0,0,1),(0,1,0), (1,0,0) \} $
- $T_1  = \{ (1,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,0,1) \}$

The remaining shape is a triangular prism.  And I'm sure that can be split into tetrahedra.  For this exercise, I need a careful enumeration of the remaning 2 or 3 pyramids, because this will get placed into another calculation (e.g. the construction of a 3-manifold).

I've narrowed it down to two possible shapes.  It is a [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone) (or [pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)) which is a "cone" with a polygonal base  ) of an equilateral triangle + another vertex.

- $T_2  = \{  ?\; , (0,0,1),\,(0,1,0), \,(1,0,0) \} $
- $T_3 = \{  ? \;, (1,1,0), \,(1,0,1), \,(0,0,1) \}$

This discussion is not terribly exciting without pictures and I apologize, I can add a few images when I have time.

[image]

My partial progress

---

Another question is *how many* ways are there to decompose a cube into tetrahedrons.  This is certainly not the only starting point. These can be connected by [Pachner moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachner_moves) which generalize the "flip" of splitting  a square into two triangles.

Here's another decomposition:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let the coordinate axes be $x, y, z$. The cube can be split into 6 tetrahedra by taking all points such that $x \le y \le z$, all points such that $x \le z \le y$, and so on for each of the 6 possible orderings. These tetrahedra are not the same shape as your $T_0$ and $T_1$, however.